# How to get drive name with libusb?

Tags: c++

How to get drive name with libusb? I use windows and next code:

```
#define VID             0x4444
#define PID             0x0001
#define PID_FILE        0x1000

//..

libusb_device **devs;
uint8_t i = 0;
uint8_t path[9];
std::string devices;

libusb_init(&ctx);
libusb_get_device_list(ctx, &devs);

while ((dev = devs[i++]) != NULL)
{
    struct libusb_device_descriptor desc;
    uint8_t r = libusb_get_device_descriptor(dev, &desc);
    r = libusb_get_port_numbers(dev, path, SIZE_PATH);

    if (desc.idVendor == VID && (desc.idProduct == PID || desc.idProduct == PID_FILE))
    {
        printf("%04x:%04x (bus %d, device %d)\n",
            desc.idVendor, desc.idProduct,
            libusb_get_bus_number(dev), libusb_get_device_address(dev));

        path[8] = libusb_get_port_numbers(dev, path, SIZE_PATH);
        path[path[8]] = libusb_get_bus_number(dev);

        for (uint8_t g = 0; g < 9; g++) {
            devices += format("X%x", path[g]);
        }

        devices += ",";
    }
}
```

In this code I getting USB path (I use a flash drive). How to get drive name, eg E:\?

Answer (score 1):

Use [WinUSB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540207.aspx) for windows, please find the [official notice](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/wiki/Windows#About).

Text snippet from office document

> This project adds Windows platform support to the libusb Open Source
>   library, in order to help developers easily communicate with USB
>   devices on Windows. Currently it supports the WinUSB and HID drivers
>   for generic USB device access as well as the libusb-win32 and libusbK
>   drivers.
>
> Take note libusb-win32 and libusbK are separated projects.
>   libusb-win32 is a Windows only project which provide libusb-0.1 API
>   compatible library for Windows and the kernel driver libusb0.sys.
>   libusbK is a Windows only project which provides a new set of API for
>   Windows and kernel driver libusbK.sys.